# How to write a node that uses libusb?

Tags: ros, rosserial, libusb

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I need to write a node to listen to a usb port via libusb. I used to do that with a simple cpp program, but I had to use sudo to open the port. How can I rosrun such a program?

By the way, I am also interested in how rosserial pkg. does the trick. Because I think open a serial port also require root privilege.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/186443/how-to-write-a-node-that-uses-libusb?/) by [ZiyangLI](https://answers.ros.org/users/3542/ziyangli/) on ROS Answers with karma: 93 on 2014-07-13

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you want to **avoid** the requirement of **root privileges** when accessing a USB device, you should **grant appropriate permissions** to your user.

For example, lets say that your USB device is located in: */dev/ttyUSB0* (I am assuming that you use Ubuntu)

If you execute "*ls -la*", you should get something like:

```
myuser@mycomputer:~$ ls -l /dev/ttyUSB0
crw-rw---- 1 root dialout 4, 64 Jul  8 08:49 /dev/ttyUSB0
```

This means that the ***root* user** and the ***dialout* group** will have **read-write permission** and the **rest of the users will not** have access. Then what you should do is to add "myuser" to the dialout group:

```
sudo adduser myuser dialout
```

This will **give myuser enough privileges** to read and write to the */dev/ttyUSB0 device* (remember to restart your session after adding the user to the goup for the privileges to have effect)

From this point on you **will not need to sudo** any more to access your USB device.

This is just an example, your case might be different. But I hope it helps.

---

Originally posted by [Martin Peris](https://answers.ros.org/users/1108/martin-peris/) with karma: 5625 on 2014-07-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ZiyangLI](https://answers.ros.org/users/3542/ziyangli/) on 2014-07-14**:
Thank you for your reply. It is clear and I believe it will work. I find another solution, which adds a rule to udev and it also works. http://bpowers.org/?page_id=15